# send jobs via psql asynchronously

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to backup a huge number of records and delete them, but I don't have complete access to database server so I can't run my script on the server. because it takes so long I need to submit jobs(say `REINDEX` for example) and then turn off my computer. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. There is pgAgent (part of pgAdmin package), that could be abused to do it, but it's not its main purpose.

Generally, to run such long queries/jobs, you need somewhere to have a `psql` session to live until it will finish. Usually, `psql` on `screen` on some kind of server - database server, or app server, doesn't matter much.